# Multiplatform C++ Project: Inclusion of platform specific sources

Tags: c++, build, cmake, multiplatform

I have for some of my classes different implementations per OS.
My source structure is like this:

- include/AExample.h
- include/windows/WindowsExample.h
- include/linux/LinuxExample.h
- src/AExample.cpp
- src/windows/WindowsExample.cpp
- src/linux/LinuxExample.cpp

the A* classes are the interfaces for the specific implementations

My current buildsystem is cmake - but at the moment its only capable of building the linux version.

In a windows build i only need to include the windows/* file and on linux only the linux/* files

I need to

- include only the files that are relevant for my current build
- choose the right implementation when i need an instance of AExample

What techniques can you recommend to realize this in a professional way?

Answer (score 9):

This is fairly easy in CMake.

Just have your CMakeLists.txt file check the platform, and add in the appropriate files or include the appropriate subdirectory as needed.

The basic syntax is:

```
IF(WIN32)
    # Do windows specific includes
ELSEIF(UNIX)
    # Do linux specific includes
ENDIF(WIN32)
```

Answer (score 2):

If the headers have the same names but they reside in different hierarchies, you can just set the -I (include path) flag correctly for your compiler. That's much easier than handling all platform dependent includes separately.

If the headers reside in the same directory and/or you want to customize stuff, you would typically do this in your C/C++ code:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
  .. include Win headers ..
#endif

#ifdef LINUX
  .. include Linux headers ...
#endif
```

I wouldn't recommend the cmake specific solution unless you are sure you don't later need to switch the build system.

Comment: This doesn't handle including different source files in the build, though.  Using CMake typically results in setting this appropriately, but then you can also include platform specific source files.  That's one of (many good) reasons to use cmake in the first place.

Comment: This is one of those techniques that is easy and works fine for small projects, but which becomes problematic when projects grow larger. _Large Scale C++ Software Design_ recommends against sprinkling platform checks all over your source. I think using the build system to manage platform specific code is best, but if you want to do it in the source itself it's advisable to use a more [highly structured organization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31304341/365496).

Answer (score 2):

Although I think using the build system to handle cross platform files is best, it is possible to simply write your source to handle it via the preprocessor. However the very common, quick and dirty method of doing this, where you sprinkle platform checks all over the code is problematic and should be avoided.

Instead you should use a more highly structured method of organizing platform specific code to avoid problems as the project grows larger.

Platform specific code should be clearly identified at the file level: For example, use a directory structure with directories for each platform and put all platform specific source files in the appropriate directory. Source files should not contain code for multiple platforms or any preprocessor platform checks (but for one exception). Furthermore, platform specific source should generally not be directly built or `#include`d. Instead, platform specific code should only be used indirectly, via non-platform specific source files which contain nothing except the platform checks and `#include`s of the platform specific files.

Example source organization:

```
src/
  main.cpp
  foo.h
  foo.cpp
  windows/
    foo.cpp.inc
  posix/
    foo.cpp.inc
```

Example source contents:

```
// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
  foo();
}

// foo.h
void foo();

// foo.cpp
#if defined(_WIN32)
#  include "windows/foo.cpp.inc"
#elif __has_include(<unistd.h>)
#  include<unistd.h>
#  if defined(_POSIX_VERSION)
#    include "posix/foo.cpp.inc"
#  endif
#else
#  error Unknown platform
#endif

// windows/foo.cpp.inc
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

void foo() {
  std::cout << "Windows\n";
}

// posix/foo.cpp.inc
#include "foo.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

void foo() {
  std::cout << "POSIX\n";
}
```

Windows build and output:

<kbd>`cl.exe /EHsc /W4 /WX src\main.cpp src\foo.cpp`</kbd>
<kbd>`main`</kbd>

> Windows

Linux build and output:

<kbd>`g++ -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Isrc src/main.cpp src/foo.cpp`</kbd>
<kbd>`./a.out`</kbd>

> POSIX

The method shown in the above example works quite well when code for different platforms can reasonably share the same file organization. If the code for different platforms is different enough that you want different file structures for each platform, then it's more difficult to use this technique, and moving over to using the build system to manage the code for different platforms becomes more clearly superior.

It's also possible to mix this technique with using the build system; code that shares file structure across platforms can use this, while modules unique to different platforms can be handled by the build system.